Authorization for non-commercial use of nRF24L01P in custom PCB (university project)
For a university project (non commercial) I am designing a PCB that uses a nRF24L01P.
I read a number of forum threads (such as FCC certification for nrf24l01+) where the need of an FCC approval is discussed.
Needless to say, the band I'm using is the 2.4-2.4835GHz band.
My understanding is that this document https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-47/chapter-I/subchapter-A/part-15 regulates transmission in the 2.4-2.4835GHz band, and §15.23 states that for home-built equipment no authorization is required (provided one designs using the best engineering practices).
I was wondering if a university project could still be considered as a "home-built" environment therefore §15.23 applies.

Close enough for Gov't Rules.  For bonus points you could include a way to measure degradation of SNR on BT or Wifi as I once did with an XP wireless radar app that measured the Wifi signal in dBm and SNR on any Wifi signal thru the RSSI in the modem.

A spectrum analyzer a scope probe will tell you how much radiation you have from your power supply, and ARM clock etc.

thanks a lot man! it's actually a full fledged cross-university project, not just a class project, but I can definitely implement your suggestions as that's going straight to my dissertation. You'll be mentioned in the acknowledgments "for the many fruitful discussions on RF engineering" :D

You can even include properties of BER vs Bd rate vs SNR from distance r^2 or Ricean Fading which disperses faded delayed reflections off every surface that isn't free space. Then how to recover 3 dB just below threshold from antenna tuning and adding reflectors will improve your BER by decades.  Even DIY antenna boosters on youtube. Gnd = 0V except when current passes thru ESL with the log (len/wid) ratio like 0.8 nH/cm +/-50% and 1 to 3 pF/cm for grounded traces. Tinned brass shields can be bought too will add pF like  embedded coplanar waves. and reduce emissions. A probe measures V/m.

The FCC measures RF quasi-peaks with an LPF in the audio band, like 15 kHz for the video BW for sweeps, because it was all about audio interference back in my day.

There's an Iranian group near me in Toronto making mesh voice and text phone USB dongles for free communication using  gofundme.
